# Downloading file from Spring controller and return String

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I've read a couple of ways to download a file from a Spring Controller methods, either returning a FileSystemResource or void and using the outputStream. 
What I want is to return a String because I want to validate the user input first. Something like...

```
public String downloadFile(BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr, ...) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        ....
        return "redirect:/showForm";
    }
    ...
    return "success";
}
```

is it possible? What alternatives do I have to do this? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. You want the client to send a download request and the server respond with a String message?

Comment: I want the client to be able to download a file, validating user's input in the server side and redirecting to another jsp/view.

Comment: If there are errors, send a redirect. If there are no errors, write the bytes to the response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is either send the user to a page, like a "It didn't work/validate" page OR send the file.

If this is the case, what we did to solve it was to return a `ModelAndView` from our handler.  You can include it as a parameter to your handler as well, and Spring will create one for you and you can just return it.  If the form input failed validation, we set the [View](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html) on the `ModelAndView` to a custom view that would set the Content-Disposition and related headers, then got the `OutputStream` from the HttpServletResponse and wrote the file out as bytes.

Something like this (pseudo code, so may need tweaking):

```
@RequestMapping("/myHandler")
public ModelAndView myHandler(@ModelAttribute("myBean") MyBean myBean, BindingResults results, ModelAndView mav) {
  if (results.hasErrors()) {
    mav.setViewName("myErrorView");  // Uses the default view you have setup, passing the name as if you returned a String
  } else {
    mav.setView(new FileOutputView(dataToOutputOrWhatever);  // Custom View class to output file as needed
  }
  return mav
}
```

However, if you want to return a String AND do the file download, then you have to jump through some hoops.  The easiest way I have found to do this is to set a model attribute that you can read on the JSP-side that either tells the JSP to call the file download or not.  Within the JSP code you would have a combination of JSTL and JavaScript to trigger the download, either using AJAX or, in the our case, JavaScript to do the download in an `IFRAME`.

Comment: I didn't know I can set a custom view class. Downloading the file via Ajax in the JSP is another possible solution. Since I don't require to redirect to another JSP anymore, my solution was simpler but I will accept this answer for my original question.

Comment: The custom View is sorta the "old way" of doing things, but I haven't come up with a better solution to allow you to return either a JSP view or a file, depending on some switch (like validation errors). I have used the AJAX-method a couple times, but I don't feel it's as "fluid", and tend to only use it when I have too.